# Find column by name and delete column

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, sidebar

I'm trying to create a script that will identify the column header that matches to the variable entered and then deletes said column.  I've got the script to work, but only if the variable is hard coded.  I'm hoping to have the script work using a variable that's passed from another function.

**Code.gs**

```
//Delete identified Product Line Priority and Roadmap tabs
function delProduct(product) {
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();

  for(var i =0;i<sheets.length;i++){
    Logger.log(i);
    if(sheets[i].getName().match(product) != null){
      ss.deleteSheet(sheets[i]);
    }
  }      
  getColName(product);
}

// Get columns to Delete in Resources tab
function getColName(product) {
  var resources = ss.getSheetByName("Resources");
  var name = product;
  delResources(resources, name);
}

// Admin delete identified Product Line in Resources tab
function delResources(sheet, name) {
  var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,sheet.getLastColumn());
  var values = range.getValues();

  for (var row in values) {
    for (var col in values[row]) {
      if (values[row][col] == name) {
        sheet.deleteColumn(parseInt(col)+1);
      }
    }
  }
}

// send list of names to the sidebar 
function getProductList() {
  var out = new Array();
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();

  for (var i=0;i<sheets.length;i++){
    Logger.log(i);
    if(sheets[i].getName().match("Priority") != null){
      out.push([sheets[i].getName()]);
    }
  }   

  var regex = /Priority/gi;
  var text = String(out);
  var splitData = text.toString().replace(regex, "");
  var myData = splitData.split(",");
  var displayData = myData.sort();
  return displayData
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.select-to-autocomplete.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <style>    
      body {
        font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
      }
      body2 {
        font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
        font-size: 32px;
      }
      body3 {
        font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
        font-size: 10px;
        color: #C0C0C0
      }
      body4 {
        font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
        font-size: 11px;
      }       
      ul{
        list-style-type: square;
        list-style-position: inside;
        padding: 0;  
      } 
      userInput{
      margin: 1px;
      padding: 1px;
      height: 80px;
      resize: none;
      }   
      userInput2{
      margin: 1px;
      padding: 1px;
      height: 300px;
      resize: none;
      }
     .logo {
         position: relative;
         display: inline;
     } 
     .imtip1 {
         position: relative;
         bottom: 150px;
         left: 0px;
         line-height: 80%;
     }     
     .imtip2 {
         position: relative;
         bottom: 70px;
         left: 0px;
         line-height: 50%;
      }   
    .text {
        position: relative;
        bottom: 240px;
        left: 0;
        color: #000000;
        font-size:14pt;
        line-height: 0%;
    }
    .text1 {
        position: relative;
        bottom: 250px;
        left: 10px;
        color: #000000;
        font-size:11pt;
    } 
    .text2 {
        position: relative;
        bottom: 250px;
        left: 0px;
        color: #000000;
        font-size:10pt;
    }      
    </style>
  </head>

     <center class='logo'>
      <img src="image.gif" onclick="google.script.run.sideBar()" width="300px" height="260px" class="imtip2" />
      <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAOEAAADhCAMAAAAJbSJIAAAAA1BMVEX///+nxBvIAAAASElEQVR4nO3BgQAAAADDoPlTX+AIVQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADwDcaiAAFXD1ujAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC" width="300px" height="80px" class="imtip1" />
    </center>
    <center class = "text" align = "center">
        <hr  style="height: 1px; width: 105%; background-color: #848484" />
    </center> 

  <form target="_top" style="padding: 10px;">
    <div class = "text2">
      <br><br>
      <center>
      <span style="color: #ff0000;"><b style="font-size: 20px;">*** CAUTION ***</b></span>
      <br><br><br>
      <span style="line-height:120%; font-size: 12px;">Select the Product from the list below to submit your request to Product Leadership.</span>
      </center>
      <br><br><br>
      <body style="line-height:80%;">
        <center>
        <b>Product:</b>    
        <select id="optionList" name="optionList">
            <option disabled selected value="">Select Product...</option>            
        </select>
        </center>
      </body>
    </div>

   <div style="line-height:90%;">
    <center class = "text2" >
        <br><br><br>
        <input class="red" type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="priority()" style="-moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #ccc; -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #ccc; box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #ccc; -moz-border-radius:3px; -webkit-border-radius:3px; border-radius:3px;"/>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input class="green" type="button" value="SUBMIT" onclick="deleteProduct()" style="-moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #ccc; -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #ccc; box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #ccc; -moz-border-radius:3px; -webkit-border-radius:3px; border-radius:3px;"/> 
    </center>

    <body4 align="right" style="right: 2%;">     
        <p>
            <a onclick="supEmail()" target="_top">Contact Support</a>
        </p>
    </body4>
    </div>

  <script>
          function onSuccess(values) {
            var select = document.getElementById("optionList");
            var options = values; //Two dimensional array
            for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                var opt = options[i];
                var el = document.createElement("option");
                el.textContent = opt;
                el.value = opt;
                select.appendChild(el);
            }
          }

          google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess)
              .getProductList();
 </script>

 <script>
    function deleteProduct(){
       var product = document.getElementById("optionList").value;
       google.script.run.delProduct(product);
       google.script.run.sideBar();
    }
 </script>

    <script>
      function supEmail() {
        google.script.run.supEmail();
      }    
    </script>

    <script>
      function priority() {
        google.script.run.addPrioritySidebar();
      } 
    </script>     

  </form>
</html>
```

When I test the script using the hard-coded 'Test' value, I'm able to get a match and the corresponding column is deleted successfully.  However, when I change `var name = 'Test';` to `var name = product;` it doesn't find a match and nothing happens.

FWIW the **product** variable is being passed from an HTML sidebar. I'm sure it's something simple and obvious and I'm starting to think it has something to do with the format of the passed variable and the output of `values[row][col]` being different. I've also tried converting both values to strings but that didn't make a difference.

I've tried to research possible fixes for the last 2 days but I haven't come up with anything yet.  I'm just not sure how to fix.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your function seems to work, although you will find a problem if there are more than 2 columns that are matched.  I think the problem is where the function is being called from the sidebar.  A simple debugging technique would be to put SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(product) into your function. This will let you see the value of the variable when the function is called.

Comment: Hi Chibs. Can you include the code that calls `testGetColumnByName` when someone enters something into the HTML sidebar?

Comment: @Aidan Thanks for the suggestion. I've tried that in past to confirm the correct value is being passed from the sidebar but that doesn't seem to be the issue.

Comment: @DustinMichels I've edited to include the full code and html as well.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi. Thanks for adding the code. I'm still not able to run the program and reproduce the problem. Is this being deployed as a web app? Or are you adding UI components to a Google Sheet? I would try adding some `Logger.log()` statements to make sure your functions are returning the things you expect. You can also use `typeof myvar` statements, in those logger calls, to check the types of characters.

Comment: @DustinMichels incorporated your suggestion and both var types are strings (thank you for helping me confirm that part).  That said, I included `.toString().trim() ` in the code when defining the var which fixed the problem.  apparently, I had leading/trailing spaces that were being passed. I'm going to consider this closed.

Answer (score 1):

I included .toString().trim() in the code when defining the var which fixed the problem.